# Как узнать версию .apk файла?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно узнать код, который узнает и задаст в String версию apk файла.

Comment: Версию какого apk файла - своего, чужого, любого? Где узнать - в андроид-приложении, на компьютере, на сервере? Не ленитесь описывать задачу внятно и подробно.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы моё приложение могло показывать версию .apk файла по пути /sdcard/Social_Network/.update/update.apk

Comment: Андроид приложение*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить версию из архива (.apk) приложения можно таким методом:

```
    public static String getApkVersion(Context context, String apkFilePath) throws IOException {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo archInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFilePath, 0);
        if (archInfo == null)
            throw new IOException("Error while reading version from file: " + apkFilePath);
        return archInfo.versionName;
    }
```

**P.S.** Не забываем получать разрешение на доступ к ФС